# Search same couple in dataframe (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe df1 and df2:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Name" : ["Alex", "Quentin", "Clara", "Gladis", "Sara" , "Xie", "Kevin"],
                   "City" : ["Seattle", "Seattle", "Paris", "Seattle", "Miami", "Portland", "Miami"]
                   })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Name" : ["Clara", "Alex", "Jacob", "Boris", "Kevin" , "White"],
                   "City" : ["Paris", "Seattle", "Portland", "Seattle", "Miami", "Portland"]
                   })
```

I want to know that how many same couples for Seattle and Miami in the two df.
In my example above the program must return 2 because I have alex-seattle and kevin-miami in both.

Without taking into account the Clara-Paris couple because my research is only focused on identical couples in the cities of Seattle and Miami.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing that you only want the same couples from Miami and Seattle you can merge them on Column City as that is the requirement.

```
df = pd.merge(df1,df2 , on = "City")
```

and then 
Subsets the dataframe which have same Names and filtering out the couples in Miami and Seattle.

```
ss = df.loc[df['Name_x']== df['Name_y']] # This happens when both dataframes have same column names 
ss1 = ss.loc[((ss['City'] =='Seattle') | (ss['City']=='Miami') )]

len(ss1) # This returns the number of couple.
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer but its not working because set the names as the index before : df1 = df1.set_index('Name')
df2 = df2.set_index('Name')

Comment: It seems that when earlier the df2 have column name Dispatch instead of 'Name'. I have edited the answer. Why are you setting the index as name . can you please elaborate.

Comment: In fact here this is only an example that I took, my project is much larger behind. For another reason I need to have the name as an index. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Filter the cities for Seattle or Miami

 set the names as the index

 concatenate on the columns

and get the length of the resulting dataframe

```
pd.concat([frame.query("City==['Seattle','Miami']").set_index("Name")
           for frame in  (df1, df2)]
          ,axis=1, join='inner').shape[0]

2
```

Alternatively, you could just use the indexes, without running `concat` :

```
first, last = [frame.query("City==['Seattle','Miami']")
                    .set_index("Name")
               for frame in  (df1, df2)]
#get the length
len(first.index.intersection(last.index))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have an invalid syntax on the "City==['Seattle', 'Miami']"

Comment: I just ran it again, and no syntax error. what version of Pandas are you on?

Comment: `first, last = [frame.query("Initial Dispatch Group==['Beta','Gamma']").set_index("Fault Code Ch A for BITE") for frame in (self.datasetA, self.datasetB)]
len(first.index.intersection(last.index)) > 1:`

Comment: I use this code for an other exaple and it's not working. For the 'Name' and  'City' it's working

Comment: I assume you ran the lines of code separately. You should also try @DavideBrex's solution